# How can I prevent or interrupt accidental copy/paste in the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, copy-paste, urxvt

When I paste into the terminal, sometimes what is in the clipboard is not what I expected.  Specifically, it is sometimes pages and pages of text from a website.

When this happens, the terminal goes crazy, blinking rapidly and spitting out `command not found` as fast as it can.

I am afraid that someday the text will contain something like `rm -rf /`.

What is the best way to:

- act when I make such a mistake?
- prevent such a mistake from occurring?

For details, I use bash in GNU screen windows in a urxvt terminal on Linux.

The usual `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-Z` have no effect in my experience.

Comment: I break a cold sweat every time it happens to me... Don't work under root and have backups. I also use a "scrap" file in a text editor to test what I copied from a web site, since with browsers you can never be sure what exactly you just copied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To safely paste, you could invoke a text editor in bash using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>E</kbd>.  The shell builtin `fc` will bring up an editor with the last command.

Short of killing the shell/terminal, I am not sure if there is any way to kill something after you have pasted something in, and it has gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Using urxvt makes this very easy. Simply enable confirm-paste in your .Xresources.

URxvt.perl-ext-common:        confirm-paste,

I *think* it comes with certain packages of urxvt or urxvt perls... But once enabled it will ask you to hit **y** or **n** on paste of primary or selection buffers, and display a line count. So if you see a million lines you can just quickly hit **n** and be done with it.